# JavaCL reading from a CLBuffer after Running Kernel

Tags: java, opencl

I am writing a program that computes N-Body simulation but I am having a problem with getting the result of the kernel after it operates. The velocity array is being calculated by the kernel but the thing is I do not acctualy know how to read the data out again with the JavaCL wrapper.

```
//CLBuffer generator convenience method
private CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> GenBuff(float[] dest)
{
    FloatBuffer ptrLX = ByteBuffer.allocate(numParticles * 4).asFloatBuffer();
    ptrLX.put(dest);
    return context.createBuffer(CLMem.Usage.InputOutput, ptrLX);
}

private void CalculateTimeStep(float e, float DT) {
    float[] params = { DT, e, this.particleMass, (float) this.numParticles };

    //Generates CLBuffers with a convenience method 
    CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> pLXBuffer = this.GenBuff(pLX);
    CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> pLYBuffer = this.GenBuff(pLY);
    CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> pVXBuffer = this.GenBuff(pVX);
    CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> pVYBuffer = this.GenBuff(pVY);
    CLBuffer<FloatBuffer> ParamsBuffer = this.GenBuff(params);
    //sets the kernel arguments
    this.NBodyKernel.setArg(0, pLXBuffer);
    this.NBodyKernel.setArg(1, pLYBuffer);
    this.NBodyKernel.setArg(2, pVXBuffer);
    this.NBodyKernel.setArg(3, pVYBuffer);
    this.NBodyKernel.setArg(4, ParamsBuffer);
    //enqueue the kernel 
    CLEvent evt = this.NBodyKernel.enqueueNDRange(que, new int[]{numParticles});
```

This is my problem because this does not actualy update the array but leaves it as it was.

```
    pVXBuffer.readBytes(que, 0, this.numParticles,evt).asFloatBuffer().get(pVX);
    pVYBuffer.readBytes(que, 0, this.numParticles,evt).asFloatBuffer().get(pVY);
```

Problem area above

```
    //And I release the temerary openCL components manualy
    pVXBuffer.release();
    pVYBuffer.release();
    pLXBuffer.release();
    pLYBuffer.release();
    ParamsBuffer.release();
    }
```

and the openCL kernel

```
__kernel void NBody(__global float *posX,__global float *posY, __global float *volX , __global float *volY, __global float *params)
{

//params
// DT -> E -> PM -> NP    
float DeltaT = params[0];
float E = params[1];
float mass = params[2];
int numPart = as_int(params[3]);

int x = get_global_id(0);
//create local variables from global variables that are used often to lower memeroy overhead
float mPosX = posX[x];
float mPosY = posY[x];
float mVolX = volX[x];
float mVolY = volY[x];
for(int i = 0; i < numPart; i++)
{
    if(i != x)
    {
        float sx = posX[i] - mPosX;
        float sy = posY[i] - mPosY;
        float r2 = sx*sx + sy*sy;
        float r = sqrt(r2);
        float r3 = r2*r;
        mVolX += sx*mass*DeltaT/(r3+E);
        mVolX += sy*mass*DeltaT/(r3+E);
    }
} 
volX[x] = mVolX;
volY[x] = mVolY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the JNA version of JavaCL.  That one is old, please use the BridJ version - see [Migrating from JNA to BridJ](https://code.google.com/p/javacl/wiki/MigratingFromJNAToBridJ).

Do you really intend to reinterpret a float as an int in this line?

```
int numPart = as_int(params[3]);
```

This will not convert 1.0f to the integer 1, it will directly interpret the bits in that float as if they were an integer, giving some number.  I think you want to look at section 6.2.4.2: reinterpreting types.  I think you actually wanted the convert_int function, which is the explicit type cast function to convert anything to integers.

Comment: Ok I made the fix the my kernel and have ported to BridJ but it still will not read out. any suggestions because the sample code on the dev website is not working...

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me.  It could be that the kernel crashes for some reason, like an out of bounds memory access.  To guard against this, you should have `if (x < numPart) {...}` surrounding your code just after the line `int x = get_global_id(0);`.  If that still does not help, I find that the easiest way to debug these kernel crashes is to comment out all the code but the two output lines, then uncomment the rest line by line.  Make sure that none of the lines generate results that are never used again as the compiler may remove them during optimisation.